# How can I change the default database used in Kohana 3?

Tags: php, database, kohana, kohana-3

I've set up a new database config in `application/config/database.php` called `staff`.

I've then made a new base model, and added a protected `$db` variable and set it in the constructor to `$this->db = Database::instance('staff')`.

When I try and replace `Db::query(Database::SELECT, $query)` with `$this->db->query(Database::SELECT, $query)`, it fails with...

> Missing argument 3 for
>   Kohana_Database_MySQL::query()

The 3rd argument I am missing is `$as_object`, which is **not** required when using the static `query()` method. <del>My guess is the static method passes this in for me.</del> It actually returns `new Database_Query($type, $sql)`.

I think I am doing it wrong.

Is there a way to overload the static `Db::query()` I usually use in different classes with the alternate database configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've then made a new base model, and added a protected $db variable and set it in the constructor to $this->db = Database::instance('staff').

You have loaded a database in your controller.

> When I try and replace Db::query(Database::SELECT, $query) with $this->db->query(Database::SELECT, $query), it fails with...

Now you are creating a query.

Next, you need to execute the query using the database you have created:

```
$result = $query->execute($this->db);
```

In Kohana v3, queries and databases are separated, so you have to tell the query which database to execute on, rather than telling the database to execute a query. The query will compile itself, then call `$db->query($sql)` itself.

You can also shortcut around loading the database:

```
$query->execute('staff');
```

Which will execute on the "staff" database.